# Javascript print lines in innerHTML from file using PHP Echo

Tags: javascript, php

In my web application I have a process that takes around 13 hours to complete and I am generating logs through out the process.  I want to display the log on a tab within the web application.  I have used JQuery, php, bash script, php and javascript in a sequence to display the values.  The following is the minimal example of my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="testPage" name="testPage">

  </div>
  <button onclick="getData()" value="submit"></button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getData() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $.post('initiateTrain.php')
      $.post('getTrainLogs.php', function(output) {
      document.getElementById('testPage').innerHTML = output;
    })
    },1000)
  } 
</script>
</html>
```

**initiateTrain.php**

```
<?php
exec("sh /var/www/html/test.sh >> /var/www/html/test.log");
?>
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
   sleep 1
done
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo 'Success'
        break
    fi
break
done
```

**getTrainLogs.php** Reads the last line of the test log

```
<?php
$line = '';
$f = fopen('test.log', 'r');
$cursor = -1;
fseek($f, $cursor, SEEK_END);
$char = fgetc($f);

while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
    fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($f);
}

while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r") {
    $line = $char . $line;
    fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($f);
}
echo $line;
?>
```

I am facing two problems...

1. The log gets displayed in a single line instead of subsequent lines.
2. The dont know how to stop the set interval after receiving the success message from the log

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to your problems are as follows:
 1. To place output on separate lines as opposed to a single line, you'll need to use either a newline character i.e. `\n`, or you'll need to use the `<br/>` tag (or enclose each line in a `<div>` or other block tag), depending on how exactly you're choosing to generate and display your data. Otherwise there will be no way for any machine or even a human to know which pieces of text belong on a new line.
 2. To stop the interval, you need to use the JavaScript `clearInterval()` function. You'll also need to capture the return value of the `setInterval()` call in a variable that `clearInterval()` can access. For example, if you do `var myInterval = setInterval(...);`, then you would call `clearInterval(myInterval);`.